# Kendo grid in angular2 - how to stop binding grid

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I have a page with a kendo grid. There can be a lot of rows. Each row has a lot of logic for each column to show/hide something or count. For 100 rows or more I have a problem with performance. I have on this page also some edit popups to change the example name. When I had a lot of data and click to change name (not connected with data in grid) it is starting to work very slow. Popup open slow and also pressing some letters on the keyboard is also very slow. When I erase a big part of columns in this grid it's working well. So I want to do something like this that when grid is loaded, don't make rendering/checking/loading it until to my command (for example start function to load grid data). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kendo grid has a performance problem with many data on one page.
They advise using paging https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-get-the-best-grid-performance.
The easiest way to resolve this was to move data to another object. I use HTML table and with ngFor. It is extremely fast when we compare this to the kendo grid